# Java - Placing of few buttons and textboxes using SWT

Tags: java, button, layout, swt

I need to place few buttons one under another and few textboxes in the same way using SWT.
When I'm doing that, they are next to each other and I cannot change it even using

```
button1.setLocation(new Point(100,20));
button2.setLocation(new Point(400,10));
```

Can I add those things to something similiar to SWING's JPanel and move/position it freely as I need? Or maybe another solution? As to let You know - I cannot use SWING here. It has to be SWT. The reason is that I have already a chart made with SWT. The buttons and textboxes should be placed so they won't be covering my chart.

Comment: Use [SWT Layouts](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html)

Comment: Specifically `RowLayout` or `GridLayout` should help you.

Comment: Alternatively you could use the WindowBuilder Eclipse plugin for visual editing.

Comment: Either using Grid or Row layout I couldn't get what I needed, because both of them is cutting my graph and I can't see him complete. Is there a way to... for example join few rows or columns? Or maybe to speify a certain position of an object?

Comment: @user3019431 Please post your code. Otherwise it's nearly impossible to see what's causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add a new control to the existing layout, but make sure you call the `layout()` on the parent `Composite`, where you have set the layout.

If you want to place a SWT control relative to another control, you can use  `org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormLayout`.